# MySql FUNCTION 'procedureName' does not exist : Asp.net C# procedure call

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to call Mysql Procedure from asp.net C# application but getting the following exception when executing query run for the procedure call.

```
FUNCTION acsm_5f011dd1e37f064.Posts_InsertPosts does not exist
```

I tried to run this procedure on MySQL by using following command and it is working fine.

```
CALL `Posts_InsertPosts`(1, null,'IN Detail tsettt2');
```

I also command type parameter before call and check code here

```
 public int RunProc(string procName, MySqlParameter[] prams)
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(procName, prams);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MySqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters["ReturnValue"];
                    if (param != null && param.Value != null)
                        return (int)param.Value;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Close();
                }
            }
   private MySqlCommand CreateCommand(string procName, MySqlParameter[] prams)
    {
        Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procName, cn);
        if (cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (prams != null)
        {
            foreach (MySqlParameter parameter in prams)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            new MySqlParameter("ReturnValue", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4,
            ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, false, 0, 0,
            string.Empty, DataRowVersion.Default, null));

        return cmd;
    }
```

but it still giving exception function does not exist.
Looking for response.thanks.

Comment: Could be a lot of things from our point of view. Please show the entire code of how you create the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`

Comment: I used runproc method and provide procedure name and parameters, please check updated code now.thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer I hope will help you. FYI, `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` seems redundant because a newly created `SqlCommand` doesn't have any parameters by default

Comment: Sorry for my last answer, I guess I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: no issue :) I solved this issue, in fact I was using Mysqlcommand in wrong way.